# Problemas con concatenación de una variable pasada por parámetro

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Estoy queriendo pasar un valor a través de `post` a otro archivo `PHP`, pero no me esta capturando el valor que quiero.

El controlador.js tiene esto:
`txt-carpeta-actual` tiene como valor = home

```
var parametros ='carpeta-actual='+$("#txt-carpeta-actual").val();

$.ajax({
    url:"ajax/obtener.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data:parametros,// aqui sigue todo el demas codigo
    type:"POST",
```

obtener.php tiene esto:

```
<?php
    include("../class/class-elemento.php");
    $resultado = $_POST['carpeta-actual'];
    echo ELemento::listar($resultado);
?>
```

La función listar() tiene esto:

```
public static function listar($resultado){
    $archivo= fopen("../data/".$resultado."json", "r");//esta url es la que no esta obteniendo el valor que quiero, la primera url deberia de verse asi: "..data/home.json"
    $respuesta = array();
    while(($linea=fgets($archivo))){
        $respuesta[] = json_decode($linea,true); 
    }
    fclose($archivo);
    return json_encode($respuesta);
}
```

Gracias de verdad por tomarse el tiempo de ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Qué tienes definido en la opción **type** de la llamada AJAX? Si no lo tienes definido, por defecto estarías enviando la información por GET por lo que al hacer: **$resultado = $_POST['carpeta-actual'];** no estarías recuperando nada.

Comment: no tengo definido type, lo hare haber que pasa

Comment: Ya corregí amigo y nada.

Comment: Te falta un punto (.) en "../data/".$resultado."json", quedaría así: "../data/".$resultado.".json"

Comment: Que Crack que sos bro, gracias , ya funciona cheque, me hacia falta ese punto.